# Trying to return search results from a txt file to GUI

Tags: python

So I am trying to write some code that needs to search through a .txt file and return the results to a basic GUI I have created. Here is my code so far. When I click the "search" button in the GUI, nothing happens.

My code so far:

```
import re

from tkinter import *

def query():
    search = lookfor.get()
    datafile = open("data.txt", "r")
    for line in datafile.readlines():
        if re.query(search, line, re.I):
            findings.insert(INSERT)
    datafile.close()

root = Tk()

lookfor = Entry(root)
lookfor.pack()

Button(root, text = "Search", command = query).pack()

findings = Text(root)
findings.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I've also tried a different way of searching the txt file:

```
import re

from tkinter import *

def query():
    datafile = open("data.txt", "r")
    for line in datafile:
        line = line.strip()
        elements = line.split("\t")
        if str(lookfor.get()) in elements[0]:
            findings.insert(INSERT, elements[1])
        elif str(lookfor.get()) in elements[1]:
            findings.insert(INSERT, elements[0])
        findings.insert(END, '\n')
    datafile.close()

root = Tk()

lookfor = Entry(root)
lookfor.pack()

Button(root, text = "Search", command = query).pack()

findings = Text(root)
findings .pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're never calling the query function...

Comment: I just realized I copied one line of code over incorrectly. I changed 

`code`Button(root, text = "Search", command = lookfor).pack() `code`

TO 

`code`Button(root, text = "Search", command = query).pack()`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon running your program, (after fixing the `query()` issue), it produces an `AttributeError`:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/usr/Documents/main.py", line 9, in query
    if re.query(search, line, re.I):
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'query'
```

Instead of using `re.query()` (which doesn't exist), use `re.search()` (which takes the exact same parameters).

---

Also, there is a `TypeError` on line 10:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/usr/Documents/main.py", line 10, in query
    findings.insert(INSERT)
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
```

This is fixed by changing the line from:

```
findings.insert(INSERT)
```

To:

```
findings.insert(INSERT, line)
```

---

Putting this all together gives the following program:

```
import re

from tkinter import *

def query():
    search = lookfor.get()
    datafile = open("data.txt", "r")
    for line in datafile.readlines():
        if re.search(search, line, re.I):
            findings.insert(INSERT, line)
    datafile.close()

root = Tk()

lookfor = Entry(root)
lookfor.pack()

Button(root, text = "Search", command = query).pack()

findings = Text(root)
findings.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! that did help